# What the configuration that is needed in order to give root power to another new user

Tags: sudo, root

in RHEL 7.9 machine we created new user - `moon`

**Note** - user moon created by `useradd` , and we give password by `passwd` command to moon user

`moon` user should be with the same strong power privilege as `root`

and in order to do it we add the following configuration in `/etc/sudoers`

```
moon    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
moon    ALL=(ALL:ALL)ALL
moon    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

but we have the following problem

we access the user moon as

```
# su moon
$ whoami
moon
```

but when we try change user to `hdfs` user from user `moon` then we get the Password prompt

```
$su hdfs
Password:
```

what the configuration that is needed in order bypass the Password , as happened on user `root`

here is example from user `root`

```
# su hdfs
```

on above example is from user  `root` and we do not need to answer about password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/sudoers` only configures `sudo`; to exercise the permissions afforded by your configuration, the `moon` user needs to use `sudo`:

```
sudo -s hdfs
```

The only user that can `su` to another user without entering a password is `root`, more precisely the user with id 0. The only way to create a `moon` user which operates in the same way as `root` is to give that user id 0 too (several users can have the same id).

To create a user with id 0, create it as usual, *e.g.* using

```
useradd -N -g 0 moon
```

then change it to id 0 using

```
usermod -o -u 0 moon
```

Comment: yes of-course , we are thinking to restricted root on some test servers, but on the same time we want to create other user with the same strong privilege as root , because our application are failed to run in case user not strong as root

Comment: BTW - just want to mention that servers are part of Hadoop cluster, all them are RHEL 7.9 version

Comment: @yael Think very carefully before you try to restrict root so that you don't totally brick your system. I'm also curious as you how you plan to restrict root other than by putting in a bunch of selinux policies. Have you considered adding capabilities to the `moon` account to give it the necessary privileges?

Comment: don't worry about it , all servers are test servers and we can re-install them from scratch if needed so this isn't the problem, about selinux is disabled, so my post is about how to gives other user the same strong privilege as root , but be aware that all configuration on our servers are for testing and learning , so even servers are damaged then we can re-install them, and our ENV is ci-cd

Comment: @yael Do you get different results from `usermod -o -u 0 -g test moon`? This should disable the check on the uid already existing. FYI, if you log in after making this change, utilities like `whoami` or programs like `ps` will show processes started by `moon` as belonging to `root`.

Comment: we try it but we get usermod: user moon is currently used by process 27919